# C program is stuck while running it

Tags: c

Ok so i made a program in c that is asking the user to choose 1 of 4 stages he would like to play in. After the user chooses the stage, the program is generating a secret code that built out of 4 chars and its between 1-6 (for example- 3516).
But i wanted to make the chars non-duplicated, so there will be no 2 numbers the same (for example- 1642 its good but 6632 its bad code).
After i made a few "if"s in my code and i ran it, it just stacked. This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int getStages();
int randCode();

int main()
{
    getStage();

    system("PAUSE");
}

int getStage()
{

    int choice= 0;

    printf("What stage would you like to choose? Choose Wisely: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    randCode();
}

int randCode()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int randFirst= rand() % 6 + 1;
    int randSecond= rand() % 6 + 1;
    int randThird= rand() % 6 + 1;
    int randFourth= rand() % 6 + 1;

     while(randFirst = (randSecond || randThird || randFourth))
     {
         int randFirst= rand() % 6 + 1;
     }

     while(randSecond = (randFirst || randThird || randFourth))
     {
         int randSecond= rand() % 6 + 1;
     }

     while(randThird = (randFirst || randSecond || randFourth))
     {
         int randThird= rand() % 6 + 1;
     }

     while(randFourth = (randFirst || randSecond || randThird))
     {
         int randFourth= rand() % 6 + 1;
     }

    char firstNumber= randFirst;
    char secondNumber= randSecond;
    char thirdNumber= randThird;
    char fourthNumber= randFourth;

    printf("%d %d %d %d\n", firstNumber, secondNumber, thirdNumber, fourthNumber);


}
```

Comment: Use a debugger and provide information where it is stuck (or solve yourself).

Comment: You are using `%d` to print the `char` which is wrong you should use `%c`

Comment: @Gopi: While you are formally right, a `char` will be passed as an `int` for variadic arguments and `%d` does take an `int`. OP likely wants to use the `char` variables not as characters but integers.

Comment: I think you need to check out [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), and find a good beginners book or tutorial.

Comment: All of the rand variables are greater than zero, so the loops can never end.

Comment: Sounds like a school-university problem. Try reading C first. Your question is pointless to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. `=` is *not* same as `==`.
   `a = b` means assign `b` to `a`.
   `a == b` means check whether `a` equals to `b` or not.
2. To check an variable for equivalence to more than one variable form expression as

   `((foo == var1) || (foo == var2) || (foo == var3) ...)`

---

```
while(randFirst = (randSecond || randThird || randFourth))
```

This is causing the problem.

What this expression does is to assign `1` to `randFirst` if any of `randSecond`, `randThird` or `randFourth` is non-zero. Otherwise assign `0` to `randFirst` (When all other remaining 3 variables are `0`)

And then if `randFirst` got assigned `1` (which is most probable) then, `while` is always `true` since in loop too `randFirst` gets assigned to non-zero number (1 to 6). So an infinite loop.

Similar thing happens with all other remaining `while` loops.

Instead use:

```
while((randFirst == randSecond) || (randFirst == randThird) || (randFirst == randFourth))
```

in all subsequent `while` expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You declare the variables `randFirst` to `randFourth` *locally* inside the loops, shadowing the other variables by the same name you have. The values you assign within the loop are only assigned to these loop-local variables.

This of course have an effect on the loop conditions (once you fix them) as the loop condition will use the function-local variables. If you enter a loop, that loop will be infinite.

Answer (score 0):

The condition in the while looop is always true and hence it goes infinite time because (a==b) is comparision where as a=b is assignment which is always true.

Comment: Unless the value of `b` is zero.